# 1950s or '60s movie with rock-like monsters that lay eggs inside people, and possibly eat them

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am looking for a movie from the '50s, maybe '60s (not sure). It's about rock-like monsters that attack people and lays eggs inside them, maybe even eat them. That is all I remember about the movie. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this movie black & white or in colour? Also, what did the monsters look like? Were they humanoid, or some other shape? And did you watch the movie in English, or some other language?